# How to grab specific result after table has been joined in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i'm able to join `3` `tables` but i want to get the specific result based on `user_id` i'm getting `null` result why?

**here is demo**:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c58f14/2

**here is my query:**

```
SELECT ifc.*,jp.* FROM interview_for_candidate_inbox ifc

LEFT JOIN jobs_applied_by_jobseeker_for_employer jbe on jbe.employee_id = ifc.user_id

LEFT JOIN jobs_posted_by_employer jp on jbe.job_id = jp.id
```

**after the table being constructed**

the same constructed table in demo:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c58f14/2 (**please run**)

when i try this for above result

```
WHERE user_id = 151 AND job_is_deleted_or_not = 0
```

i'm getting blank result where **BLANK RESULT DEMO**:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c58f14/3

please help me thanks in advance

Comment: the maximum user id available in the sample is 151 then you wont see the result if you give 152

Comment: @VISHNURadhakrishnan, sorry you are correct for `user_id` `151` only i will edit my question

Comment: When we update the query with user_id = 151 AND job_is_deleted_or_not = 0 we are getting the result, so if you need any other help

Comment: @VISHNURadhakrishnan, thanks for the help thats all i wanted to test the query, now it is working fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because

```
WHERE user_id = 152
```

Didn't match anything.

If you rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM interview_for_candidate_inbox ifc

LEFT JOIN jobs_applied_by_jobseeker_for_employer jbe on jbe.employee_id = ifc.user_id

LEFT JOIN jobs_posted_by_employer jp on jbe.job_id = jp.id

WHERE job_is_deleted_or_not = 0;
```

You will find distinct user_id values, none of them is 152

Comment: @rkosengi, i want to get all results where `user_id = 152 AND job_is_deleted_or_not = 0`

Comment: Then your query is correct, but there is no such data!